# How to count rows by group in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I have a SQL query that returns data which includes quote types along with customer information.  There are 4 types of quotes (Open, Dead, Requote, Project).  I want to be able to count each type for each customer.  And also count the total.  I have not found a way to accomplish this.

Ultimately I want this to go into a gauge on an SSRS report so that we can tell how many of the quotes (percentage) eventually turn into a project.

I haven't found anything in my searches that works.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: next time try to provide a 
 [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) with a schema and some data so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
 much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Look for `COUNT`  and  `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CTE's

```
 WITH quoteTotal as (
      Select customer, count(*) as customer_total
      from customer
      group by customer
 ),
 typeQuote as (
      Select customer, quote_type, count(*) as quote_total
      from customer
      group by customer, quote_type
 )
 SELECT T.customer, T.quote_type, T.quote_total, Q.customer_total
 FROM typeQuote T
 INNER JOIN quoteTotal Q
    ON T.customer = Q.customer
```

I think using window functions can be easy.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       customer, 
       quote_type,
       COUNT(*) OVER (partition by customer, quote_type order by customer) as type_total,
       COUNT(*) OVER (partition by customer order by customer) as customer_total
FROM customers
```

Comment: Sorry about the limited amount of data that I was able to give you.  But thank you very much for taking the time to come up with this query.  After some tweaking it is working the way that I want.

Comment: Did you use cte or window version?

Answer (score 0):

For the data as below:

[image]

I have executed the query below

```
select  CustomerEntityId,QuoteType,
(select count(QuoteType) from Customers c
    where c.QuoteType=Customers.QuoteType
        and c.CustomerEntityId=customers.CustomerEntityId
    group by CustomerEntityId,QuoteType) as QuoteTypeTotal,
(select count(*) from Customers c1 
    where c1.CustomerEntityId=Customers.CustomerEntityId 
    group by CustomerEntityId) as CustomerTotal
from Customers
Group By CustomerEntityId,QuoteType
Order By CustomerEntityId
```

The result is as below :

[image]

I hope it helps.